# Central limit theorem implications about $\bar{X}$

Tags: convergence, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

The central limit theorem (CLT) and law of large numbers (LLN) look to make the same claim.

$$\text{CLT: }\sqrt{n}\big(\bar{X}_n-\mu\big) \rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2) $$

$$\text{LLN: }\bar{X}_n \rightarrow \mu
$$

It sure looks like some algebra can get you the LLN from the CLT.

$$\sqrt{n}\big(\bar{X}_n-\mu\big) \rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2) $$

$$\implies \big(\bar{X}_n-\mu\big) \rightarrow N(0,{\sigma^2}/{n}) $$

$$\implies \bar{X}_n \rightarrow N(\mu,{\sigma^2}/{n}) $$

$$= N(\mu, 0)$$

$$= \mu\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\square ? $$

Now, the LLN makes milder assumptions than the CLT (finite variable not required) and gets stronger convergence than the convergence in distribution that the CLT gets us. However, this algebra-looking argument sure looks like it gets us somewhere.

Where, if anywhere, does the algebra-looking argument break down? Is it something to do with having the convergence being to a moving target (different $N(0,\sigma^2/n)$ for each $n$)?

Comment: you are very lose with definitions here, clean up your first two equations

Comment: Convergence in distribution to a point mass implies convergence in probability, so your reasoning holds (under the more strict assumptions of the CLT).